# Is it possible to create a view in other database with EXEC?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm currently writing a stored procedure which shall be executed on database A.
It loops over other databases and shall create a view there if it can not find it. Here's a snippet:

```
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('['+ @source_db+'].['+@source_schema+'].['+@current_table+']', 'V') IS NULL
    BEGIN
    print('source view not available for ' + @source_db ) 
    print('creating view')
    EXEC('USE ['+@source_db+']; create view ['+@source_schema+'].['+@current_table+'] as select * from [XYZ].[' + @dc_guid + '].[' + @current_table+']' )
    print('view created')
    END 
END
```

But the EXEC statement obviously not works, since the View Statement must be the first one of a batch. But separating the use command to another EXEC statement doesn't work either (I found out that both EXEC statements are completely separate from another). As far as I know (and also tried out) it is not possible to use the "Go" command within EXEC.

What else can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution can be encapsulating the creation of the view inside *another* dynamic SQL which will be executed after the connection changed database.

```
DECLARE @dynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 

    'USE AnotherDatabase;

    EXEC(''CREATE VIEW dbo.TestyView AS SELECT 1 AS Something;'')'

EXEC (@dynamicSQL)
```

If printed...

```
USE AnotherDatabase;

EXEC('CREATE VIEW dbo.TestyView AS SELECT 1 AS Something;')
```

And successfully creates the view.

Comment: So simple, so good. Makes sense and works fine. Somehow I got stuck and didn't think about the solution. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can make no use of `USE` and just call `sp_executesql` from db that you are interested in.

Here is an example of how to create a view `vDateView` in every database (`system databases` excluded) if it does not exist:

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb
'
if db_id(''?'') > 4 and
 not exists 
(
select *
from ?.sys.objects
where type = ''v''
and name = ''vDateView''
)
exec ?.dbo.sp_executesql N''create view dbo.vDateView as select getdate() as dt''
'
```

In this code `?.dbo.sp_executesql` executes `sp_executesql` in the context of `?` database

Comment: Ah interesting. Didn't know of that until now. Has this some advantages/drawbacks over the other variant?

Comment: No advantages, just another way to do the same thing. sp_executesql can be called as db.dbo.sp_executesql and this means you have no need of USE. And sp_MSforeachdb is just another way to do smth for every db

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks :-)